# In pytorch, why is there a difference in indexing a tensor between these methods

Tags: multidimensional-array, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor of shape: `(batch_size, max_length, embedding_dim)`.

Each sample corresponds to a sentence (a list of tokens).
I also have a list indices, one per sample of shape `(batch_size)`. I'd like to collect the embedded vector that corresponds to the index in each sentence into a tensor of shape: `(batch_size, embedding_dim)`. Sounds simple right?

However, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with these options:

```
# option 1, doesn't work:
torch.gather(batch, dim=1, index=indices)
# option 2, doesn't work:
torch.index_select(batch, dim=1, index=indices)
# option 3, doesn't work:
batch[:, indices]
# option 4, the one that works:
batch[range(batch_size), indices]
```

What are the differences? How to use each properly?

Thanks